# Identify the discontinuity and mark it as incremental event in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe, I need to increment the event_id when a discontinuity observed in the column. Here for the given data below, if the difference between the current data and the previous data is >5 then the succeeding column has to be mark with next event_id.

```
id, data,       event_id,

aa, 2,      1,

aa, 4,      1,

aa, 6,      1,

aa, 12,     2,

aa, 14,     2,

aa, 15,     2,
```

I tried with below code,

```
df['pre_data']=df.groupby('id')['data'].shift(1)
df['diff_flag']=np.where((df['data']-df['pre_data'])<5,1,0)

df['event_id']=df['diff_flag'].ne(df.groupby('id')['diff_flag'].shift()).cumsum()
```

But the code is giving the output of event_id as (1 ,1,1,2,3,3) while the expected output is (1 ,1,1,2,2,2)

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand well your problem you need to increase the `event_id` every time the difference is more than 5.
In this case the solution is in your code you just need to change this

> `df['diff_flag']=np.where((df['data']-df['pre_data'])<5,1,0)`

to this:

> `df['diff_flag']=np.where((df['data']-df['pre_data'])>5,1,0)`

and return:

> `df["diff_flag"].cumsum()`

because the `numpy where` is the oposite of `pandas where` in numpy we update the value that match the condition